# What is DirectX 11's equivalent of D3DCAPS9::MaxVertexIndex of DirectX 9?

Tags: directx, directx11, directx9

I'm porting a DirectX 9 program to DirectX 11. How do I get the value in DirectX 11 that is retrieved using

`D3DCAPS9::MaxVertexIndex`

in DirectX 9?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Please do not cross post questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Answer (score 1):

The place to start is on MSDN's page on [Direct3D feature levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876.aspx).

The row 'Max Vertex Index' indicates the value you are after:

```
11.1: 2^32 – 1
11.0: 2^32 – 1
10.1: 2^32 – 1
10.0: 2^32 – 1
9.3: 1048575
9.2: 1048575
9.1: 65534
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no value for this listed in the [Direct3D 11 Resource Limits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819065(v=vs.85).aspx) I don't think there is a limit. However according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471324(v=vs.85).aspx) 9_1 feature level devices only support 16-bit index buffers.

Comment: Ah... I see Chuck Walbourn answered this question better on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24811074/3826372